# Close connection mysql2 node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

When should a connection be closed, so the script is not interrupted?

I put "connection.end()" after each "query" but it always shows an error

If i do not close the connection, then the code works, but waits for closing

```
const connection = await mysql.createConnection({

  host: config.host,

  database: config.mysqlMainDatabase,

  user: config.mysqlUser,

  password: config.mysqlPassword

})

const fillTables = async () => {

  const [result_1] = await connection.execute(`SELECT DISTINCT(f_1) FROM t_1`);

  result_1.map(async result_item => {

    await connection.execute(`INSERT INTO t_2 (f_1) VALUES (?)`, [result_item.m])

    const [result_mm] = await connection.execute(`SELECT DISTINCT(f_2) FROM t_1 WHERE f_1 = ?`, [result_item.m])

    let jsonM = []

    result_mm.map(async result_m => {

      jsonM.push(result_m.mm)

      const [result_ym] = await connection.query(`SELECT DISTINCT(f_3) FROM t_1 WHERE f_1 = ? AND f_2 = ?`, [result_item.m, result_m.mm])

      let jsonY = []

      result_ym.map(result_y => {

        jsonY.push(result_y.y)

      })

      await connection.query(`INSERT INTO t_3 (f_1, f_2, f_3) VALUES (?,?,?)`, [result_item.m, result_m.mm, JSON.stringify(jsonY)])

    })

    await connection.query(`INSERT INTO t_2 (f_1, f_2) VALUES (?,?)`, [result_item.m, JSON.stringify(jsonM)])

  })

}

await fillTables()
```

Answer (score 0):

When closing connection after each query You will need to create a new client instance in order to use it after you closed the previous one.

You don't need to close a client connection after every executed query. Close it when all your queries Finished (at the end of `fillTables` function):